# save svg to .svg with foreignObject

Tags: d3.js, svg

I use [saveSvgAsPng](https://github.com/exupero/saveSvgAsPng) to get svg`s dataUri. Then  I converted the dataUri to .svg by Java.The original picture had foreginObject tag.When I save it to .svg,and open it with chrome,the foreignObject tag do not show.This is my .svg tag

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="1477" height="1033" class=".save" style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)" id="saveImg" viewBox="-201.48349917081265 -185.1995003306789 1477 1033" preserveASpecRatio="none" version="1.1">
  <g>
     <g class="textGroup">
       <text>This is test</text>
     </g>
     <g>
       <foreignObject x="200" y="50" width="200" height="200">
         <div>
           <p style="color:rgb(0,0,0)">this is P</p>
         </div>
       </foreignObject>
     </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

As you know,Directly with chrome open. svg do not have `<html>`and `<body>`

Comment: Try to check output svg file, the div element inside foreignObject element has (x)html namespace or not.  The parsing rule of svg tag in HTML context is not same in XML(SVG) context(=stand alone SVG). If you want to treat div element as HTML's div in XML context, you should add HTML namespace to it.

Comment: I seem to understand ,Thanks